# SVN MATLAB issue

Tags: matlab, svn

I see two contradictory messages

[image]

All the folders below are under the euv-algorithm-pilot folder above.

[image]

Even after SVN cleanup, why do the 5 conflicted files exist?

Answer (score 1):

`svn cleanup` != `svn revert`

[Per SVNBook | `svn cleanup`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html):

> Recursively clean up the working copy, removing working copy locks and
>   resuming unfinished operations. If you ever get a working copy locked
>   error, run this command to remove stale locks and get your working
>   copy into a usable state again.

However, it seems that you want to revert local modifications in your working copy. In this case you need to use the [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) command. Note that reverting a working copy is irreversible operation and should be performed with caution.